# JAXB remove XmlRootElement wrapper

Tags: xml, json, jaxb, marshalling, jaxb2

I have this @XmlRootElement class Person.

```
    @XmlRootElement
    class Person {
        private String desc;
    }
```

and the return content is

```
    {"Person": {"desc": "abc"} }
```

and I really don't want the root wrapper, so I want the content to looks like

```
    {"desc": "abc"}
```

Can I accomplish this via JaxB? If so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JAXB is an API for XML, not JSON.

However, there are some JSON libraries (at least Jackson) which can utilize JAXB annotations. I don't know which one you are using, so I don't know exactly how to best help. (If you are using this with the Jersey framework, it uses Jackson for its JSON serialization.) You will need to configure whatever JSON library you are using to be able to configure the "wrapping" of the root element in the JSON output.

I wrote up this quick Groovy script to test this in Jackson:

```
@Grab('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.2')
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature

@XmlRootElement
public class Person {
  public String desc = "howdy"
}

Person p = new Person()
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE)
println om.writeValueAsString(p)
```

As it is written above, it outputs the JSON:

```
{"Person":{"desc":"howdy"}}
```

If you take out the part `.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE)` it gives you:

```
{"desc":"howdy"}
```

So if you are using Jackson, it looks like the ObjectMapper that is being used behind the scenes is being set to `WRAP_ROOT_VALUE` and you just need to turn that off.

Comment: thanks! can I set JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT in a properties file. I am using CXF with jettison

Comment: In the [Apache CXF documentation for JSON support](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/json-support.html) (under "Using ServerFactoryBeans"), it shows the instantiation of `MappedXMLInputFactory` and `MappedXMLOutputFactory`. My guess is (I've never used Jettison) that you could set your configuration on those.

Answer (score 4):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

As [answered by esseplymale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18421298/383861) JAXB (JSR-222) covers XML not JSON binding.  Howvever JAXB is frequently used directly (a JAXB impl used with something like Jettison to convert JSON to/from StAX events, see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/jaxb-and-json-via-jettison.html) and indirectly (a JSON-binding implementation interpreting a subset of JAXB annotations) in this space.

Below is how you could accomplish your use case by leveraging EclipseLink MOXy as your JAXB provider.

### Java Model

**Person**

Below is the `Person` class from your question.  I have added the `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` annotation so that I could avoid adding the accessor methods (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html).

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Person {

    private String desc;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

You use MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html).

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

There are a few things to note in the demo code:

1. The `JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE` property is used to put MOXy in JSON-binding mode.
2. The `JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT` property is used to tell MOXy to omit the root element.
3. When the root element is omitted you need to tell MOXy what type you are unmarshalling by using one of the `unmarshal` methods that take a `Class` parameter.

```java
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Person.class}, properties);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StreamSource json = new StreamSource("src/forum18417466/input.json");
        Person person = unmarshaller.unmarshal(json, Person.class).getValue();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(person, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.json/Output**

```java
{
   "desc" : "abc"
}
```

Comment: thanks! can I set JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT in a properties file. I am using CXF with jettison.